# What contributing factors would make the Florida “gain time” bill be signed into law in 2021?

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws, florida

A.) Are there contributing factors that would effect whether the Florida “gain time” bill will be passed by the House in 2021? Is so, what are they at this current time? I heard that some House members have already spoken favourably about this bill. The bill would reduce the current mandatory time sentenced that a prisoner must serve from 85% to 65 percent.

B.) The bill has a predetermined “effective date” of July 1, 2021. Is this any indication that the bill is likely to be passed?

https://www.flsenate.gov/Session/Bill/2021/1032/BillText/Filed/PDF#page=5

Page 10 discusses 65% rather than 85% as retroactive gain time.

Comment: What is that bill? Providing some basic information about the bill you are asking about would help.

Comment: I agree that this is on-topic here on Politics, but I'm also not sure how answerable it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Background**

The Florida legislature meets for only 60 days per year. This year's session will begin March 2, 2021, and last through April 30, 2021. *See*, [2021 Session Dates](https://flsenate.gov/Session/Calendar/2021/Session%20Dates%202020-11-18%20162817.PDF). Bills not passed during the session expire at the end of the session. The activity currently underway is consideration by committees. [SB 1032: Gain-time](https://flsenate.gov/Session/Bill/2021/1032?Tab=BillText) was introduced February 3, 2021, and has not yet been assigned to any committee, in particular, the Senate Committee on Criminal Justice which must review the bill. Bills considered in 2020, relating to "gain time", died in committee.

**Questions**

> A.) Are there contributing factors that would effect whether the Florida “gain time” bill will be passed by the House in 2021? Is so, what are they at this current time?

The bill will first be considered by the Senate, then, if passed, will be sent to the House.

SB 1032 was submitted by [Senator Keith Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Perry_(politician)), who "founded the House of Hope, a Christian-affiliated rehabilitation center for recently released prisoners" and whose district includes [Lowell Correctional Institution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowell_Correctional_Institution). Perry is also a member of the Committee on Criminal Justice.

The two factors that may improve the prospects for passage this year are

- the objections to last year's bills may have been addressed this year and
- Sen. Perry may be a more knowledgeable advocate for passage.

> B.) The bill has a predetermined “effective date” of July 1, 2021. Is this any indication that the bill is likely to be passed?

No. Bills have effective dates whether passed or not. The bills from 2020 had effective dates of July 1, 2020, and they all failed.